# Trim URL in 3 different format with Google Spreadsheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am looking for some help to trim URLs in Google Spreadsheets to the root domain, subdomain, Subdirectory and URL. The sheet has subdomain,  and numeric parameters in column A; what should be the formula that I have to implement to get root URL data?

For example, I have a url called https://www.web.stackoverflow.com/question/ask/how-to-trim-url-in-3-different format-with-GPF, but I need data in this format:

```
First Column: https://www or https://
Second Column: stackoverflow.com
Third Column: web.stackoverflow.com
Fourth Column: stackoverflow.com/questions
Fifth Column: stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Sixth Column: web.stackoverflow.com/question/ask/how-to-trim-url-in-3-different format-with-GPF
```

I tried to learn it with the some formulas, but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:ftp:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")))
```